# Fourier transform of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, expected-value

If I have a stochastic process, which is normally distributed then expectation is:

$$
E[g(x,t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,t) p(x) dx
$$

where $p(x)$ is the Gaussian probability density function. I'd like to take the Fourier transform wrt $x$ but I'm not sure how this will work.

Comment: $x$ is the integration variable, so you cannot take Fourier transform with respect to $x$.

Comment: Since the expected value operation eliminates $x$ and returns only a function of $t$, call it $g(t)$, then the Fourier transform of $g(t)$ with respect to $x$ is $g(t)\cdot 2 \pi \delta(\omega)$.  Which is probably not what you're really looking for.  Can you add more detail to your question?